Supabase client fails in Nuxt 3 client-only build despite configuration
I'm encountering an error when building my Nuxt 3 app for client-only use:
500
@supabase/ssr: Your project's URL and API key are required to create a Supabase client!


My nuxt.config.ts includes:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  supabase: {
    url: process.env.SUPABASE_URL,
    key: process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
    // ... other options
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      SUPABASE_KEY: process.env.SUPABASE_KEY,
      SUPABASE_URL: process.env.SUPABASE_URL
      // ... other config
    }
  },
})

Environment variables are correctly set. How can I resolve this for a client-only build?

I'd suggest hardcoding the values to see if it work first. If that works then the issue is with your build system and not the Supabase library at all. Also I think the Nuxt team has their own nuxt-supabase package that you're supposed to use.
